# How to push a branch to github after amending a commit?

Tags: git, github

I have amended a commit in a branch(not the master branch) in my local repo using this code `git commit --amend --no-edit` but how to push this to github? I had already pushed the branch before amending the commit. Now i just want the change to commit in my local repo(done using  `git commit --amend --no-edit`) to be reflected in github also. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force push the branch:

```
git push --force origin some_branch
```

The reason why an ordinary push will fail is that in the process of amending the top most commit, you actually have *rewritten* that commit entirely.

Here is a diagram showing what `some_branch` would look like after amending the head commit:

```
remote: ... A -- B
              \
local:          B'     (the prime indicates a new commit)
```

In other words, from Git's point of view it is as if your local and remote branches have actually diverged from each other.  Now, the `A` commit is the most recent ancestor.  You probably want to keep your local version, and if so then you need to force push.

Comment: git push -f origin some_branch does this also give me the same result, found this somewhere or is there any difference?

Comment: No...you are using the short version.  They do the same thing.

Comment: sure, Thank you